# Aeroo report in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, aeroolib

Getting an error while configuring Aero report in Odoo.

> Failure! Connection to DOCS service was not established or convertion
>   to PDF unsuccessful!

[image]

i have used https://github.com/Yenthe666/AerooInstallScript/blob/Stable/aero_installer.sh

this script to install aeroo report.

Thank You

Comment: Have you started the aero-docs service?

Comment: configparser.duplicatesectionerror : while reading from ' /etc/aeroo-docs.conf' section start already exist.

Comment: issue solved.Corrected the aeroo-docs.conf file and restarted the server